# How to design REST API with complicated property?

Tags: design-patterns, rest, api

I need to design an Restful API resource and it's quite a complicated resource in that i need details about other resource to define my property.

Currently I have 3 solution.

1. Creating the related resource as a property until I have the
   granular detail I need.

   - Pros: Efficient
   - Cons: breaking open / closed principle as we'll need to modify the existing related resource or duplicate it.
2. Creating a flat resource that defines the properties from other
   resource.

   - Pros: Simple
   - Cons: Inefficient as a lot of information will be duplicated.
3. Similar to #1 but instead of adding calculations as properties to the related resource, create a reference to them.

   - Pros: Efficient and allows to use actual related resource without modifying it.
   - Cons: Complex relationships.

Resource (solution #1)

- Calculations

  - RelatedItem -> RelatedSubItem -> RelatedSubSubItem -> Calculation#1,
    Calculation#2, Calculation#3
  - RelatedItem -> RelatedSubItem ->
    RelatedSubSubItem -> Calculation#4, Calculation#4, Calculation#5

Resource (solution #2)

- Calculations

  - Calculation#1 Property
  - RelatedItemDetail
  - RelatedSubItemDetail
  - RelatedSubSubItemDetail
  - Calculation#2 Property
  - RelatedItemDetail
  - RelatedSubItemDetail
  - RelatedSubSubItemDetail
  - Calculation#3 Property
  - RelatedItemDetail
  - RelatedSubItemDetail
  - RelatedSubSubItemDetail

  ...

Resource (solution #3)

- Calculations

  - RelatedItem -> RelatedSubItem -> RelatedSubSubItem -> Id#1
  - RelatedItem -> RelatedSubItem ->
    RelatedSubSubItem -> Id#2
  - Calculation #1 -> Id#1
  - Calculation #2 -> Id#1
  - Calculation #3 -> Id#1
  - Calculation #4 -> Id#1
  - Calculation #5 -> Id#2
  - Calculation #6 -> Id#3

Comment: You should have a look at [HATEOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS)

Comment: How about [GraphQL](http://graphql.org/), or maybe [OData](http://www.odata.org/)?

Comment: Also, your question would be better with an actual example, rather than generic words and numbers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you for the comments about using the different approaches.

In the end we decided to just come up with a data structure with the correct associations instead of using the related item and modifying them. We created a custom version of the object so it is clear that it is not the same object but did reuse it where appropriate (AssociatedSubSubItem).

CustomRelatedItem -> CustomRelatedSubItem -> AssociatedSubSubItem (Property), Calculations (#1, #2, #3) (Property)